# Removing invalid values to correctly recreate cumulative data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set with statistics that I collect from text. The processing method sometimes does not work correctly, and I need to correct the output data. I know they are supposed to be cumulative, but sometimes I get incorrect data.

Time series data that should accumulate over time. Right now I'm getting the following, sample snippet:

```
df
date         value
2021-07-20   21347.0
2021-07-24   21739.0
2021-08-02   22.0
2021-08-03   22.0
2021-08-06   22947.0
2021-08-17   4.0
```

As you can see, the data is cumulative, but some values are defined incorrectly.
I would like such values to be converted to `nan`.

How can I do that? The final result is expected to be as follows:

```
df
date         value
2021-07-20   21347.0
2021-07-24   21739.0
2021-08-02   nan
2021-08-03   nan
2021-08-06   22947.0
2021-08-17   nan
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `numpy`:

```
df['value'] = np.where(df['value'] < df['value'][0], np.nan, df['value'])
```

Output:

```
   date         value
0  2021-07-20   21347.0
1  2021-07-24   21739.0
2  2021-08-02   nan
3  2021-08-03   nan
4  2021-08-06   22947.0
5  2021-08-17   nan
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this solution is not very suitable for me, because. I process several sources at once for individual cities, and the data differs in them. I can't bind a string to a specific number in the check

Comment: Just modify it a lil bit. Replace 21347.0 in the less than condition with ```df['value'][0]``` and you can use it with multiple datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
import numpy as np
df['check']=df['value'].shift(1)
df['value']=np.where(df['value']>df['check'],df['value'],np.nan)
```